# OR clauses or array membership checking

Tags: c#, arrays, list

In a simple `if` statement, I check if variations of a device serial-number string can be identified, and if yes, then I proceed to do a few more things.

I am now wondering if it might be more efficient to place the variation strings in an array and check if any of them exists in the serial-number?

Currently, I do it this way:

```
if ( args.RecognizedText.Contains("ABNK-33-X") || args.RecognizedText.Contains("ABNK-88-X") || args.RecognizedText.Contains("ABNK") || args.RecognizedText.Contains("-SS-X") || args.RecognizedText.Contains("-83-x") || args.RecognizedText.Contains("-38-x") )
{
    layoutShifter.DisplayLayout("CorrectDeviceFoundLayout.xml");

    var ocrWebcamCanvas = UnityEngine.GameObject.Find("OcrWebcamCanvas");

    if (ocrWebcamCanvas)
    {
        ocrWebcamCanvas.GetComponentInChildren<OcrWebCam>().StopCoroutine("ScanOcrAtIntervals");
        ocrWebcamCanvas.GetComponentInChildren<OcrWebCam>().StopWebcam();
    }
}
```

Would it make a difference if I put all the variations in an array and checked for membership?

Comment: This would be more readable.

Comment: i prefer a list or dictionary because that'll be more flexible and maintainable

Comment: The or would technically be faster but it's probably so a little you would never notice.  The contains array would be easier to maintain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test is redundant.

You are checking if the text contains:

> "ABNK-33-X" or ABNK-88-X" or "ABNK" or "-SS-X" or "-83-x" or "-38-x"

You can remove the first two tests as if the string contains "ABNK" it, by definition also contains ""ABNK-33-X" or ABNK-88-X". I don't know whether you can remove the other three tests or not.

Another optimisation would be to order the search strings by frequency. Then the code will perform the fewer comparisons when matching the strings. Only the rarest inputs will have to be checked against all possible patterns.